# Vendor Bundle Size Not Reducing

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm trying to get my build much smaller to get my load time faster, but when I run

`ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --build-optimizer` and then run a lighthouse report from google dev tools

I get

[image]

what's odd is that it seems to have worked if I go into the dist folder to look at file sizes, which seem smaller that the lighthouse report.

[image]

So far to reduce the size by doing the following:

- Removed old/unused package.json entries
- changed all material imports to specific path like for paginator I'm importing now as 
  `import { MatPaginator } from "@angular/material/paginator";`
  instead of `import { MatPaginator } from "@angular/material/";` per the advice from other posts.
- replaced moment with moment.min.js so that locales don't get added
- added brotli for text compression.

Also I want to mention because I don't know if it's relevant, but I don't have a `webpack.config.js` file only a `custom-webpack.config.js` for brotli. The only thing I edited in angular.json to get webpack working was this for brotli

```
  "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
             },
```

I've never used webpack before so this could be an issue, but I'm not sure.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mean-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:server": "nodemon backend/server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "ably": "^1.1.22",
    "angular-doka": "file:src/angular-doka",
    "angular-filepond": "^1.0.5",
    "azure-arm-rediscache": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "countdown": "^2.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "filepond": "^4.13.4",
    "filepond-plugin-file-encode": "^2.1.5",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.0",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.5",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "^2.0.3",
    "filepond-plugin-image-edit": "^1.6.0",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.7",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.1",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "^2.0.4",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "^3.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lib-storage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "material": "^0.4.1",
    "moment-mini": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.20",
    "ngx-filepond": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-light-carousel": "^1.0.37-beta.8",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-simple-countdown": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.2.1",
    "ngx-ui-carousel": "^1.3.2",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tsoa": "^2.5.7",
    "uid": "0.0.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "8.4.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.59",
    "brotli-gzip-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```

Here is a stats.json file when using `ng build --prod`

[image]

Here's a more detailed version as well

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache since you made the changes or using an incongnito browser? Maybe your old bundles are chached and the browser keeps using those.

Comment: show image of vendor.{hash}.js created from stats.json.

Comment: I added more detailed version above

Comment: @Narm I'm using chrome incognito to run lighthouse report

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: are you using all modules of material in your project?

Comment: I'm using Angular 8. ```ng --version``` outputs: https://pastebin.com/6mTuqF6D I'm not using all modules in material, but I am directly pointing to the ones I am using in my components like in bullet points example from question

Comment: in modules how are you importing material modules, are you using pipeable operators of rxjs?

Comment: Do you mean in components? For example, In the components, If I'm using multiple material modules, then I break them up the imports in that component so I can be more specific like so: https://pastebin.com/7BXvg2Rd. Also I am using .pipe whenever subscribing like this ```.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(result => {``` Besides that I'm not really using .pipe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214924/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-user6680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove libraries like ngx-spinner, filepond etc. which are huge as they are not treeshakable. Also if you have not configured your server to serve gzip files, do that. It will give you huge reduction in size. Also pre gzip your js files after build my using a utility like gzip-all.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-all

Also change your server max cache policy to get caching benefits.